# How do I fix eslint createRequire is not a function in Atom Editor?

Tags: node.js, eslint, atom-editor, eslint-config-airbnb

I had a difficult time tracking this down, so I'm posting to help others who search for a similar error.

---

I decided to set up a new project on Ubuntu 18.04 in Atom with eslint and Node.js.

ESlint, by itself, installed and ran just fine with my config extending `eslint:recommended`, but when I installed `eslint-config-airbnb-base` and changed my config to extend `airbnb-base`, I started getting an error in Atom and it would not parse my files.

`Error while running ESLint: createRequire is not a function.`

Removing airbnb and relying on `eslint-plugin-import` gave a similar error:

`Error while running ESLint: Failed to load plugin 'import' declared in '.eslintrc.yaml': createRequire is not a function.`

However, running eslint on the command-line worked fine.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is a compatibility issue.

[This change to eslint](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/commit/2c28fbbb563a44282bef0c9fcc9be29d611cc83b) removed a polyfill that supported node versions below `v10.12.0`

I was running Atom 1.45.0, which uses node `v10.11.0`. Running eslint from the command line worked because I have node `v12.18.2` installed there.

So you have two of options to fix the issue:

1. Upgrade your Atom Editor (at the time of writing, version 1.49.0 is the latest, which uses node version `v12.0.0`). If that's not possible for you then...
2. Downgrade eslint to version `6.8.0` (the last release before 7.0.0). This version still contains the polyfill for `createRequire`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Second option worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 1):

hello you can easily fix these issue.
make sure to check in the terminal the node version you have installed
if it's outdated then update the node using node version manager
in  the terminal,type the command
$ nvm install node 14.15.0
current lts version of node is 14.15.0.once you install lts version of node
$node -v
..14.15.0
$npm -v
..6.7.0
now start the development server,
$npm start

these time it won't show any error